# spring boot integration test - reuse with and without mock

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have a number of test cases for integration tests. My code to test is communicating with external REST API's hence the integration tests needs to mock this API. However, as I am also able to run the same tests in an environment where the external APIs are available, I would like to be able to structure my tests such that running in one profile it uses the mocked version of the APIs and in another profile, they will use the actual APIs available.

Is this possible with spring boot test - and what would the correct approach be?

Comment: use `@Profile` for each given type and then run test only with given profile which you need.

Comment: @bilak Yes - my question goes more in the direction of how to handle the shared test cases and the mocking / non mocking setup - profiles will be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

For mock, you can run a mock web server and configure it to return whatever response you are expecting in your test. Two such popular mock servers are WireMock and MockServer.

When you want the mock, you'll replace the URL to use localhost:mockServerPort instead of your external API and start the server in a before class method before all tests, and shut it down after the tests are complete.

You can reuse the same test code. Create an abstract class with the tests, and two subclasses, one using the external URL, one using the mock URL. These URLs can be set using the `properties` attribute of `SpringBootTest`.

[WireMock](https://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/)

[Spring Boot Integration Tests With WireMock and JUnit 5](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-integration-tests-with-wiremock-and-junit-5/)

[How to Automate Tests for Spring Boot API using MockServer](https://medium.com/@gavinklfong/how-to-automate-tests-for-spring-boot-api-using-mockserver-c6221ea8c549)

[Introduction to MockServer](https://www.baeldung.com/mockserver)

[Running MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/running_mock_server.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your API is a Spring Bean, you should be able to provide the bean as part of your test. Depending on environment variables or system properties (or Spring profile), return the real Bean or the fake one:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApiTest {
  @Autowired private Environment env;
  @Autowired YourService service;

  @Bean
  public YourApi api() {
    if (Object.equals("true", env.getProperty("use_real_api"))) {
      return new YourApi();
    } else {
      return Mockito.mock(YourApi.class);
    }
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
     service.callApi();
     // assert, verify, …
  }
}
```

Feel free to extract the bean definition into a `@Configuration` bean and import it from your test (`@Import` or `@ContextConfiguration`).